# Regular expression for mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, html, regex

I am working on a scrapping script which gets the date from source file. I want to extract a date time field, can any one give me the regular expression for that.

I currently do have regular expression for date:

`"(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)"`

this will only check for mm/dd/yyyy but not for time stamp.

Currently trying to make this regular expression

`"(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20) (0?[0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([012345]?[0-9]):([012345]?[0-9]):([012345]?[0-9])\\d‌​\\d)"`

I think it needs some changes.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you facing a specific problem? We're not a coding service.

Comment: I did mention the regular expression currently I tried in the post

Comment: I think what is meant is what have you tried in order to solve the particular problem you are asking us about e.g. a regex for timestamp.

Comment: Yes, I tried the regular expression which only gets any text of the format mm/dd/yyyy, but I also want to modify my regular expression to pick only the fields which have mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS.

Comment: And have you tried to modify it yourself yet?

Comment: @Pav And have you tried to add that other pattern?

Comment: Yes, but I think it is not exactly correct since it is not able to pick up the timestamp. "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20) (0?[0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([012345]?[0-9]):([012345]?[0-9]):([012345]?[0-9])\\d\\d)".

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Comment: It looks like you are not the author of regex which can match `mm/dd/yyyy` but you found it somewhere and now you are asking others to create another one which can also match timestamp. You need to know that people tend to help more willingly if they see some prof that someone at least tried to solve problem on their own (asking others or searching for ready solutions doesn't count). So try to [edit] your question and include your attempts to write your own regex which you think should solve your problem and we will try to correct your mistakes.

Comment: Firstly, I am new to regex, but I did make the query for the first part. It's just I am sure it has to do something with the \s space, but not sure how to keep the space between Date and Time part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"([0-2]\d:[0-6]\d:[0-6]\d)?" will take care of the timestamp part. Now just combine the two

Comment: This will also match `29:69:69`. You probably wanted `([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d`.

Comment: I was doing military time, but forgot about the upper 20's. My bad

Answer (score 0):

So finally this is the answer which worked successfully. Thank you everyone for your help.

"(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\d\d)\s+([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)"

It was the issue with space, some fields have some than one space in between the date and timestamp.